# "Navigation to the webpage was canceled" when create new mfc project in vs2008

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2008, mfc, internet-explorer-8, project

I have a strange problem in vs2008.When I create new MFC project this popup window open with messege **"Navigation to the webpage was canceled."**

[image]
I have been repair my visual studio but the problem remains there.

After turn off Internet Explorer from Windows features.

[image]

Comment: try reset your IE options in the advanced tab

Comment: I have turn off Internet explorer from window explorer,but problem remain same.

Comment: Try some of the suggestions here? [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvc/thread/40fde5ae-a179-42af-91f6-e2c488b5375f)