# webbrowser html path

Tags: html, winforms, browser

I have a winforms project which uses javascript in an html page to puts a google map onto a webbrowser. The html page build action is 'Content', the copy to output directory value is 'Always' and the full path is the same as the path supplied to the webbrowser.url.

This works fine in the VS2010 development environment and after publishing it on the development machine, but after moving the published project to another machine the webbrowser initialization fails with the message "This program cannot display the web page".

I've run out of ideas, so any suggestions would be gratefully received.

Comment: This question is not about the Google Maps API V3. (tag removed)

Comment: That narrows it down a bit, then

Comment: Not really. I'm only saying that your question is not about the Google Maps API. The question is only about how to use Visual Studio, regardless of what content you put on your webpage. ;-)

Comment: Did you install to a folder whose name contain space and used a file uri? Last time I checked you need to replace space with %20.

Comment: Sheng Jiang - thank you for the suggestion.  The one-click install puts the application in C:\Users\MCMS\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\W2275YAW.6MG\81WQHVY4.8JT\mapw..tion_d84a3c9200359120_0001.0000_576bb191867472c4

Comment: ClickOnce deployment put your application in a less trusted zone... if you reference a script on local computer you may get this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210566/navigation-to-the-webpage-was-canceled-when-create-new-mfc-project-in-vs2008#comment16356787_12210566 Try use the marker of the web to change your page's zone.

Comment: It seems the link between the webbrowser and the htm file is lost during the publishing.  The answer elsewhere in stackoverflow suggests building the url dynamically:             string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            this.webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(String.Format("file:///{0}/HTMLPage4.htm", curDir));